# Difference between Auth::logout() and Session::flush()

Tags: laravel

For some reasons, i cannot use `Auth`. So, instead `Auth::logout()` i'm using 
`Session::flush()`.

My session driver is **database**.

I have two questions:

1. What's the difference, *internally*, between these methods (`Auth::logout()` and `Session::flush()`)?
2. There is some risk for me when using `Session::push()` for login and `Session::flush()` for logout users?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from laravel documentation:

Removing All Items From The Session
  Session::flush()

So, if you use session::flush and have data in your session it will be deleted.

Why you cannot use Auth::logout()? How did you login the user then?

Comment: because i'm using *OctoberCMS* and `Auth` is kind of boring to get it